# bash: send signal from python script to a process

Tags: python, bash, unix, process

I have `server.py` and `client.py`.

I want to **run both** from a **single bash script**, and **client** starts **after** the **server** has been initalized (unknown time).

The script i've got so far:

```
python3 run_server.py &
python3 run_client.py
```

I know about `os.kill()` but:

- I dont know client's PID in advance
- 'kill' sounds wrong since I want server to live

I am **very noob** in both python and anything related to os

Comment: what happens when `run_server.py` has finished instanciating ? Is there a message written ? Does the script stop with a specific status ?

Comment: right now it waits for connections on a socket, thats it. stopping with a status could be a solution

Comment: Making the client poll the socket until it is able to connect could be a way to go

Comment: Why do you think you want to send a signal? And do you want the client to send a signal to the server? Or the server to send a signal to the client?

Comment: `kill` is badly named, it sends a signal.  However, signal handling is very tricky with many hidden dangers (very few functions are signal-safe).  You should explain why you think you need to send a signal, there are safer ways to synchronise processes.

Comment: What i want is synchronization between processes such that second process starts strictly after some point of execution in first process. I dont know what the hell is a signal, i just know that it exists out there and thought that it would apply

Comment: @cdarke i would gladly use the safest synchronization way, especially at my current knowledge level

Comment: Why not start the second process from the first one then?

Comment: @cdarke server should be independent of a client. I am looking to writing an actual server that works in abstract environment

Comment: How do we know when the correct point to start the client has been reached?  The server must give some indication that it is ready for clients to start.  Either that, or (as said above) have the client start first and poll the server's port for a connection.

Comment: @cdarke lets say some thread in a server environment blocks on `socket.accept()`, that means that server is ready to serve

Comment: But a process outside of the server is not going to know when that is the case, unless you tell it or the client is polling.

Comment: @cdarke i see what youre talking about. That might be the answer